# Additive Paragraph

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

A friend of mine who knows I like puzzles recently sent me this short letter:

> Heya Will! Here's a quick puzzle I call Additive Paragraph!
>   Solving method: identify a single unsaturated locution inside each row,
>   hunt within flowery text and locate simple foundations,
>   and also, you're disallowed building onto word edges.
>   That's all! Kind regards, Lucy :)

The envelope was empty apart from this note.
It'll be pretty embarrassing if I can't solve it...  hey, help me out here!

Comment: [fear of looking stupid](http://www.socialanxietysupport.com/forum/f26/so-scared-to-look-stupid-41743/) is nothing to be embarrassed of.

Comment: Sorry, but Lucy is MY friend. She calls 'Will', not 'Theg'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> **chalk**.

The solving method ...

> ... is described in the riddle: There's exactly one word on each line that can be made into another word by inserting a letter. (A word is "saturated" when no more letters can be added. The unsaturated words are "foundations" for new words.) The new letter cannot be added before the first letter or after the last letter of the word: we can't build onto word edges.
>
>  The inserted letters spell the answer:
>  addi **c** tive / 
>  s **h** ingle / 
>  h **a** unt / 
>  wor **l** d / 
>  Luc **k** y